# How to bind to a click to toggle a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given a list of LIs each LI includes a checkbox like so:

```
<li class="contact">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkableitems[]" value="1333">
    <div class="content">
        <cite>Baby James</cite>
    </div>
</li>
```

I would like to be able to toggle the checkbox on LI click, not just on checkbox click. I got this work which you can see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/xgB5X/2/

The problem is, while clicking on the LI toggles the checkbox, click on the checkbox directly is no broken. Clicking on the checkbox no longer toggles. Any suggestions to get this working? Thanks

Comment: Why not use a `label` instead of an `li`

Comment: The <OL> has about 500 <LI>s are you saying use a label inside of the LI?

Comment: @AnApprentice, the amount of `<li/>` elements is irrelevant for us, specially if you don't say nothing about it

Comment: @AnApprentice If you use a label, clicking on the label automatically checks and unchecks the checkbox

Comment: It doesn't seem like anyone mentioned this, but have you simply tried binding the event on the .content instead. using `$('.listview li .content')` should make it work. One other minor edit you will need then is to add `parent()` to use: `$(e.currentTarget).parent().find('.checkbox');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of notes:

use .prop() instead of .attr() (it's also easier to tell true/false on it, must each other through all browsers.

You can check the e.srcElement for your classname of checkbox within the click().

```
$('.listview li').on('click', function(e) {

  if (e.srcElement.className === 'checkbox') {
      e.stopPropagation();   
      return;
  }

  checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');

   // Toggle Checkbox
   if (checkbox.prop('checked')) {
       checkbox.prop('checked', false);
   } else {
       checkbox.prop('checked', true);
   }

});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pQCMR/)

Answer (score 4):

Why not using `label` tags?

```
<li class="contact">
    <input id='input1' type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkableitems[]" value="1333">
    <label for='input1'>Baby James</label>
</li>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xgB5X/5/)

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/xgB5X/3/ Check this.

I've added a little bit of code to stop the propagation. This will prevent the event to reach to the `li` tag.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Your problem was when the checkbox was clicked it was changing its state, but when the event reach to the li tag as it contains the check box once again it was changing its state.

Comment: Thanks but then there are 2 bindings for this. Anyway to make this work with a single binding?

Comment: yes, doing an if ( e.srcElement.className = 'checkbox' ) { e.topPropagation(); }

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this ***[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sNJLV/1/)***

```
$('.listview li > *').children().bind({
    click: function(e) {
        checkbox = $(this).closest('li').find('.checkbox');
        checkbox.attr('checked', !checkbox.is(':checked'));
    }
});​
```

Comment: Thanks, is the magic here "li > *" ? What does that do exactly? thanks

Comment: @AnApprentice Any direct descendent of the selected element.

Comment: that selector selects any immediate children of LI. * is a wildcard and > is children. so we're saying bind click to any children of li

Comment: ok so the real magic here is how you are finding the checkbox? For some reason that's not working in my code, still trying...

Comment: also changed the checkbox selector since the context changed to the children not the li.  checkbox = $(this).closest('li').find('.checkbox');

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.listview li').on('click', function(e) {
      var c = $('.checkbox', this);
      c.prop('checked', !c[0].checked);
}).find('.checkbox').on('click', function(e) {e.stopPropagation();});​​​​​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xgB5X/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Even though I think you should use a label for this here is method working

```
$('.listview li').bind({
  click: function(e) {
      var checkbox = $(this).find('.checkbox').get(0);
      if (e.target == checkbox) return;
      checkbox.click();
  }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xgB5X/9/)